# Cannot use delete key in src layout

Tags: linux, gdb

I have enabled src layout with command `layout src`, now I find the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key not functioning.

When I press that key, the gdb prompt says `J`. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this the delete key on the numeric keypad or the delete key in or next to the main keyboard?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It's a laptop, only one Delete key ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your active window is not the gdb command window. Press `C-x o` to change the active window.

To invoke the relevant gdb info page: `info gdb 'TUI' 'TUI Keys'`

Comment: No, it is active. I can press ^D to remove the character. am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. In particular: _The TUI associates several key bindings (like scrolling and arrow keys) with the active window._ Not all key bindings are associated with the active window.

Comment: Yeah, I did see extra border on the src window. Now I know which one is the active